# Guidelines for storing uploaded photo info in database

Tags: php, mysql, photo, uploading

We are making a social site for a client (final project for classes) and he wants a photo uploading feature.

We thought about putting a link in a MySQL database to the picture with a unique ID for the picture and also a foreign key to the User ID.

But I was wondering what would be the safest method.

1. Should we keep the picture name or rename it?
2. Should we keep all pictures within the same folder, or have a separate folder for each Unique User ID?.
3. If we rename the picture, should we just start with the unique ID for the picture? (1 to  XXXX)

Safe : any type of explointing with a malicious filename
Fastest : to have 1 folders then XXXXX folder

Comment: I would create user-directories and leave the image names untouched. That way the photos will have meaningful names when downloaded or viewed directly.

Comment: You should explain what do you mean by safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For uploaded images I would rename the image to the userid-imageid so an image would be named 123-5554.jpg for example, this would group them by userid while keeping them in the same folder (using sorting), and provide a unique name for each image.

If you dont rename the image, someone could easily upload a image called picture.jpg more than once.

Comment: Or at least ADD the imageid to the end of the image name so that it keeps its meaningful name (if it has one) as @feeela suggests

Comment: This seems like the best awnser atm

Comment: @Vincent Matte also if you want a descriptive name for the image you could just add a image description field along with the image upload field on your form, and of coarse a image description field in the image table in your database. THen you could have 100 people call a picture "My House" but each image would still have a unique file name.

Comment: Yeah, there will be a description field for sure!

Answer (score 0):

I would change each pictures filename to something unique. Each picture should have a unique id in the table as well. Then you can set a foreign key on the picture's unique id to the user's id.

Your second question is kind of your own preference, depends on the kind of structure you would want to have. I would create a separate folder for each user, its more intuitive and a little easier to navigate if there is a lot of data.

Comment: what if the same user uploads picture.jpg from my documents and picture.jpg from my pictures, and they are different pictures? It would overwrite the old picture, or you would have to test if the picture already exists in the servers folder and tell the user they cant do that and force them to rename pictures on their personal computer.

Comment: I find it really anoying when a website ask me to rename it localy